# Ignore routing rule if condition is not met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I want to catch URLs that contain a `+` sign in its' second segment.

If it doesn't contain that character the rule should be ignored alltogether.

I'm trying to do it with [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) like this:

```
get ":topic/:cities", to: "cities#show", constraints: {cities: /.*\+.*/}
```

But unfortuantely the code above overrides and catches as well requests meant for this single segment URL:

```
get ":topic", to: "topics#show"
```

**Why is this, what am I doing wrong?**

**And secondly, is there any better way to accomplish a conditional situation like the above in `routes.rb`?**

Comment: In what order did you write those rules? Did you try with the 

    get ":topic", to: "topics#show" above the other constrained rule?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the prioritizing principle, and no that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your show action includes the id so your constraints regex is also catching it. Change constraint regex to `[a-z]+\+?[a-z]+`. Hope that helps.